# Writing to BQ25700A with i2c_smbus_write_block_data

Tags: raspberry-pi, smbus

I'm trying to write to a TI buck boost charger (BQ25700A) using the i2c_smbus_write_block_data command, to try to provide current to a battery.

```
byte current_reg[2];
current_reg[1] = n & 0xFF;          //LSB       //This is not getting written
current_reg[0] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;   //MSB
i2c_smbus_write_block_data(deviceDescriptor,0x14,2,current_reg);
```

n here is the applied current. Can be anything between 0-2000 (in milliamperes). The 0x14 register will discard all the extraneous bits and keep only the 6-12 bits. You can see this in the datasheet images i've attached below.
My issue is that current_reg[0] is written to the charger register, but the LSB
i.e. current_reg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DSLb.png) doesn't seem to go through. Consequently, I get only 256mA of resolution through the charger, instead of the 64mA (since the LSB is what contains that information).

The relevant datasheet excerpt:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are swapping the LSB and MSB, so you are sending the MSB first.

Fix the code to send the LSB first.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. This was one problem, but it also seems like the function i2c_smbus_write_block_data was in itself buggy. I changed my code to instead use i2c_smbus_write_i2c_block_data, alongwith the interchanging of the LSB and MSB, and it now works. Thanks!